# Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I compile a project on Android Studio, I found this error.

I have download the NDK.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: add this `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in your `gradle.properties`

Comment: There is a simpler way as mentioned in thi slink: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791429/error-your-project-contains-c-files-but-it-is-not-using-a-supported-native-bu

Comment: A specific and straightforward question, that other questions link to as a "possible duplicate", with the exact issue I'm looking for... that was closed for no reason.  I think people just like closing questions because it makes them feel like they're "contributing", regardless of whether it actually makes sense or not.

Comment: Since this question was closed for no reason I can't post the answer here.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880334/136829

Answer (score 73):

Put this part in `build.gradle(Module:app)` above `buildTypes{}`

```
sourceSets {
   main {
     jni.srcDirs = []
   }
}

buildTypes{
   //...
}
```

Comment: This is the solution you need if you don't need recompilation of C sources. Requires .so to already be built.

Comment: For some reason using this suggestion made it possible to built the project, but at runtime it crashes saying the function is not available. Can you please check it out: https://github.com/tinntt/android-system-record-track/issues/2#issuecomment-400562115 ?

Comment: did not work for me. the same error is showing.
What is the value of    jni.srcDirs = []

Answer (score 11):

Add this line to your `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: No longer works

Comment: Deprecated NDK is no longer supported. To avoid that error remove android.useDeprecatedNdk=true 
then edit the build.gradle(Module:app) below buildTypes block and add those line like in this link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51947296/6067690