# while implementing Project I am facing this " Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
>    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
>   or use the experimental plugin:
>    http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.

Comment: It's actually duplicate of *[Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065871)*

Answer (score 4):

Add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in your `gradle.properties`

here is mine

```
  # Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental is also an option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791429/error-your-project-contains-c-files-but-it-is-not-using-a-supported-native-bu

Comment: yeah, depends on the user pref. @sgupta