# Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build

Tags: android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj3fk.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065871/error-your-project-contains-c-files-but-it-is-not-using-a-supported-native-bu)

Answer (score 42):

It seems that you already have the C++ code, and the Makefiles in the project directory, in which case, you simply have to link Gradle to the native library:

1. In your project pane, **right-click** on your module, and select **Link 
   C++ Project with Gradle**.
2. From the **drop-down** select either **CMake** or **ndk-build**, depending on your project

   a. If you selected **CMake**, specify the **CMakeLists.txt** script in your project

   b. If you selected **ndk-build**, specify the **Android.mk**.

*Source:* https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#existing-project

Comment: Can you please mention Android.mk or CMakeLists.txt path location. I found multiple files with this name.

Comment: You can find your Android.mk in; app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug.

Comment: @Voltshan there is no ndk folder inside intermediates in my case. What should i do?

Comment: @Janman i follow your answer but now android studio saying Android.mk file doesn't exist. Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 14):

The Android plugin these days shows a better explanation.

> * What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>   > Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>     Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
>      http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
>     Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
>      https://developer.android.com/studio/build/experimental-plugin.html.

There are essentially two options: either to use the integrated externalNativeBuild, or to disable it.

1. The best approach for the first option was [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364491/192373) by **[Janman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595216/janman)** here.

   I would not recommend using the [*experimental plugin*](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/experimental-plugin.html) these days, because I believe that **ndk-build** integration is much more powerful. But simple projects may be easier to maintain with the experimental plugin.
2. Alternatively, you can choose for some reason to build the native libraries outside the Android Studio. To prevent the error message, I know three options.

   1. You can disable the gradle task: in **build.gradle**, add

      ```
      tasks.all { task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('compile') && task.name.endsWith('Ndk')) {
          task.enabled = false
        }
      }
      ```
   2. You can [hide the cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40400058/192373) from Android Studio, e.g.

      ```
      sourceSets {
        main {
          jni.srcDirs = []
        }
      }
      ```

      The drawback of this approach is that the cpp files are not indexed by Android Studio.
   3. Another [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461489/192373) is to add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to **gradle.properties**. It is not clear, though, how long this flag will be working.

Answer (score 4):

New Solution add this to your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        version "3.12.0"
    }
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to gradle.properties file.

Comment: Oops, Build works, but when I run the project.
I have the same problem. the issue not resolved. but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this.
First of all, do not make any **white space** in the Project Directory.
Then edit the ***build.gradle(Module:app)*** and add those line like me.

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/','src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Comment: Android.mk file is not found.so what i do?

Comment: @Shomu have you solve this problem? I am facing same problem Android.mk  file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed the dependencies LLDB, CMake, and NDK
   if not ,select SDK TOOLS from Tools > Android > SDK Manager check the 
   corresponding boxes and apply.
2. take the build.gradle in app and search for

   ```
   sourceSets { 
       main { 
           jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLBS/'] 
       } 
   }
   ```

   and comment this line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Working on OpenCV Project in android studio 3.3.1.  I Faced same Problem and found Solution by Installing CMake, LLDB and NDK under Tools-> SDK Manager -> Android SDK-> SDK Tools.
2. Add following to build.gradle(Module:app)

   ```
   externalNativeBuild {
           cmake {
                       version "3.12.0"
           }
           ndkBuild {
                       path 'build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk'
           }
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Very important is delete this line in build.gradle (Module:app).

sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }﻿

Answer (score 0):

You must care about you sourceSets in gradle(module.app) and see what is your lib folder name for your jni 
for example, my folder name was jniLins so I hade to remove the jni folder from sourceSets but the best way is to put the array empty so that It can read from the exixting folder
I mean instead of

```
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
```

write this:

```
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = [] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple places you can put an "externalNativeBuild" block that mean different things.  It needs to be in both the android { } block and the android { defaultConfig { } } block.  If the outer one is missing, you'll get this.  A working example from here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/super-sphere/blob/master/dist/android/love/build.gradle  The "ndk" block doesn't seem to be needed.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "-j2"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution but a quick on is to set 'NDK deprecation' for 60 days in `gradle.properties` by adding this line:

```
android.deprecatedNdkCompileLease=1608114817403
```