# Execution failed. Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>     Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
>      https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
>     Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
>      https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791429/error-your-project-contains-c-files-but-it-is-not-using-a-supported-native-bu)

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Execution+failed.+Your+project+contains+C%2B%2B+files+but+it+is+not+using+a+supported+native+build+system&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=yJy8WqzjHaPpugSsvJm4Bg