# android.useDeprecatedNdk=true is no longer supported

Tags: opencv, gradle, android-ndk

I try to use `OpenCv` to build a facetracking camera app but I have a problem when I set up my `OpenCv`.
I have this error [image]

I use the `android.useDeprectedNdk=true` in `gradle.properties` but it doesn't work.

Comment: So, what is unclear in the error message you got, it is quite extensive?

Comment: actually it tells you what to do... it says that you should not use this, but if you really want to use it... add to the properties `android.deprecatedNdkCompileLease=timestamp` where timestamp is 60 days in the future i guess... it seems bigger than the normal timestamp....

Answer (score 11):

**Deprecated** NDK is no longer supported. To avoid that error **remove** ***android.useDeprecatedNdk=true*** and do not make any **white space** in the Project Directory. If errors come again
then edit the ***build.gradle(Module:app)*** below *buildTypes block* and add those line like below:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
       ......................
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/','src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this solution just removing the line in the Gradle file giving the error?

Comment: Yes, I think 'build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk' may not exist (not generated at all).